# JavaFX TabPane : Why is the content not refreshed after selecting different tab?

Tags: javafx, tabpanel

So I am currently working with tabpane in JavaFx for the first time.

After it didn't work as expected I reduced the tabpanes content one bit at a time until it looked like this:

```
<ScrollPane prefWidth="Infinity" prefHeight="Infinity" fitToWidth="true" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
                            fx:controller="de.Cos4U.ui.scene.control.CosplayView">
    <VBox alignment="top_left" minWidth="200" prefHeight="200" spacing="5">

        <TabPane prefHeight="Infinity" minHeight="Infinity">
            <tabs>
                <Tab text="Tab1">
                    <content>
                        <Label text="test"/>
                    </content>
                </Tab>
                <Tab text="Tab2">
                    <content>
                        <Label text="tests2"/>
                    </content>
                </Tab>
            </tabs>
        </TabPane>
    </VBox>
</ScrollPane>
```

After selecting "Tab2", the content area still shows the label "test". It is refreshed as soon as you scroll. It's a this simple tabpane, so why doesn't it refresh its content?

Edit: I am using 1.8u74 right now. I edited the fxml so now its as complete as needet but as reduced as possible.
The controller doesn't affect the tab pane in any way so. So far it handles simple user inputs. After removing anything i don't need for this example, it is reduced to 0.

Comment: Post the complete FXML (and controller if needed) to provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please include the parts that needed to reproduce the behaviour. "As you scroll" - with what? `TabPane`s chage their `Tab`s normally and what you have posted is a standard `TabPane`.

Comment: Also post the version of JavaFX you're using : I had some refreshing problems while using the version 1.8u60.

Comment: I am using 1.8u74.

Comment: I use a pretty dirty workaround for now. Whenever a tab is selected i programmatically increase and decrease the stage-width a little bit. This enforces a repaint.

Comment: @Shiniji Kudo Hello i am having the same issue but also when i am adding new Tabs to the TabPane , are not showing if i don't resize the window a little bit :(

Answer (score 1):

I used to have the same problem. I don't have the exact reason why it doesn't update correctly, but if you want to force a refresh of the Layout, you can request it instead of using a workaround like changing the size.

```
requestLayout();
```

Suppose you want to set the content of a tab inside your controller.

```
class Panel extends TabPane {
    private Tab tab;

    public void setTabContent(Node container) {
        tab.setContent(container);
        getSelectionModel().select(tab);
        requestLayout(); // to force refresh the layout
    }
}
```

You then call this method from your controller.